# Is there a way to use GumtreeDiff to get diff infomation between two commits?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-difftool

I want to use Gumtree to get diff info, but in gumtree wiki, I only find how to use gumtree to get diff between files.

[GumTreeDiff](https://github.com/GumTreeDiff/gumtree)

Comment: It would probably help if you included a link to [GumtreeDiff](https://github.com/GumTreeDiff/gumtree) in your question.